# Are all HttpError in python subclasses of IOError

Tags: python, ioerror

In our code we catch IOError and log it before reraising. I am getting a "connection reset by peer", but nothing in the logs. Is "connection reset by peer" a subclass of IOError in python?

```
     .....
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 1047, in readline
    s = self._read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 1003, in _read
    buf = self._ssl.read(self._bufsize)
error: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

Comment: The title reads now as "Are all HttpError in python subclasses of IOError". The answer is trivially "no", because you can define a HttpError class in your own code that derives directly from Exception. Do you mean something like "all the exceptions raised by the urllib library" instead?

Comment: > "Do you mean something like "all the exceptions raised by the urllib library" instead?"

Umm, yes.

Comment: Then please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: When you read the source for the urllib, what did you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace you pasted looks like some Exception of class `error` with arguments `(104, 'Connection reset by peer`).

So it looks like it's not a HTTPError exception at all. It looks to me like it's actually a [socket.error](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.error). This class is indeed a subclass of IOError since Python 2.6.

But I guess that's not your question, since you are asking about HttpError exceptions. Can you rephrase your question to clarify your assumptions and expectations?

Comment from usawaretech:

> How are you finding out it is a socket
>   error? MY code is something like:
>   try:risky_code(); except IOError:
>   logger.debug('...'); raise; As I am
>   assuming that HttpError is a subclass
>   of IOError, when I get that exception,
>   I am assuming that it be logged. There
>   is nothing in my logs

I guess it is a socket.error because I used the [index of the standard library documentation](http://docs.python.org/genindex-E.html), and because I encountered this error before.

What version of Python are you using? I guess it's Python 2.5 or earlier.

If your intent is to log and re-raise exceptions, it would be a better idea to use a bare except:

```
try:
    risky_code()
except:
    logger.debug(...)
    raise
```

Also, you can find the module where the exception class was defined using `exception.__module__`.

Comment: How are you finding out it is a socket error? MY code is something like:

try:risky_code(); except IOError: logger.debug('...'); raise;

As I am assuming that HttpError is a subclass of IOError, when I get that exception, I am assuming that it be logged. There is nothing in my logs.

> So it looks like it's not a HTTPError exception at all. It looks to me like it's actually a socket.error. This class is indeed a subclass of IOError since Python 2.6.

I am on python 2.5